# GROUP BY using parameters in Ads Data Hub (BigQuery)

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-data-hub

I am working on Google ads data hub and am relatively new to bigquery (sql in general).
In a certain case, I am trying to do a dynamic group by based on a parameter input (I believe the parameter needs to be an array?)

So if say my table has four fields (two are numerical and two are string)

And I want a scenario where I am doing a group by on either one of the string variable or both of them together

So based on my paramter input, my data will be grouped by on the selected input and a certain mathematical operation would be applied to the numerical data (say average)

Currently, I can just make combinations of different string columns (lets say I have age and name as my columns so I have one age column, one name column and one age_name column) but this workaround falls apart when my string columns go beyond a number since there will be way too many combinations possible.

Is there a way to dynamically provide what columns I want to group by my table on and select those columns and numerical values (post aggregation) in my output?

Sample Input :

| Pokemon | Location | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jolteon | City1 | 230 |
| Jolteon | City2 | 210 |
| Umbreon | City2 | 240 |
| Umbreon | City2 | 180 |
| Umbreon | City3 | 180 |
| Espeon | City3 | 260 |
| Espeon | City3 | 100 |
| Espeon | City4 | 300 |

If I supply @hierarchy paramter as a string array. The aggregation logic is average here.

Output if input is "pokemon"

| Pokemon | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Jolteon | 220 |
| Umbreon | 200 |
| Espeon | 220 |

Output if input is "pokemon,location"

| Pokemon | Location | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jolteon | City1 | 230 |
| Jolteon | City2 | 210 |
| Umbreon | City2 | 210 |
| Umbreon | City3 | 180 |
| Espeon | City3 | 180 |
| Espeon | City4 | 300 |

Note: Please note that this is just in the case of 2 fields but if my potential paramater input can have more than 3,4 factors and final output have data grouped by those 3,4 factors and then the pre decided aggregation logic on the numerical fields.

Comment: Please provide simplified example of input data and expected output to support described logic - so we can understand your case and will be able to help you

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Thank you for the guidance. Have provided sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try [EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate):

```
DECLARE columns STRING;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mytable as
select "Jolteon" as pokemon, "City1" as location, 230 as value union all
select "Jolteon", "City2", 210 union all
select "Umbreon", "City2", 240 union all
select "Umbreon", "City2", 180 union all
select "Umbreon", "City3", 180 union all
select "Espeon", "City3", 260 union all
select "Espeon", "City3", 100 union all
select "Espeon", "City4", 300
;

SET columns="pokemon, location";
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "SELECT " || columns || ", AVG(value) as value FROM mytable GROUP BY " || columns;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I believe EXECUTE IMMEDIATE does not work in Ads Data Hub Bigquery

Answer (score 0):

> If I supply @hierarchy parameter as a string array ...

Consider below

```
DECLARE hierarchy ARRAY<STRING>;
SET hierarchy = ['pokemon', 'location'];
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || ARRAY_TO_STRING(hierarchy, ',') || 
', AVG(value) as value FROM `project.dataset.table` GROUP BY ' || ARRAY_TO_STRING(hierarchy, ',');
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

In case of `SET hierarchy = ['pokemon'];` - output is

[image]

Comment: Hello, I believe this EXECUTE IMMEDIATE function is not supported by Ads Data Hub. Due to data privacy issues, I cannot extract the data onto bigquery and execute this. I need to perform any aggregations on the platform UI itself which uses bigquery

Comment: this answer is for BigQuery (based on Tag you provided for your question)